# Continued fractions, why the reciprocal?

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions

Why is  the reciprocal of the fractional part (vs the integer part) taken at each step?  Perhaps this is obvious, if so I don't see it.  Appreciate your guidance.

Example from Wiki showing reciprocal taken at each step:

[image: cf]

Comment: Why would taking the reciprocal of the integer part be useful?

Comment: They need to get a 1 in the numerator, so a remainder of  49/200 is the same as 1/(200/49). The 49 is not useful in the numerator but the 1 is.

Comment: If you did that, the next step would have 0 integer part and then the algorithm would crash because you can't take the reciprocal of 0.

Comment: @SenZen yes, but how is $1/f = r$?  In step 1 I thought $r$ is $49/200$, but it is really $f$.

Comment: @Nick In step 1, $r = 649/200$ and $f = 49/200$???

Comment: @ruferd there is not a value of $1/(200/49)$ like you mention above. Using the example graphic, first $f = 1/(49/200) = 200/49$.  I read the Wiki page on continued fractions and still cannot find the reasoning behind the reciprocal.  Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It's just the Euclidean algorithm.

$$\cfrac{649}{200}=3+\cfrac{49}{200}=3+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{200}{49}}=3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{4}{49}}=3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{49}{4}}}=3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{12+\cfrac{1}{4}}}$$